# Direct field access in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to use direct field access for "command objects" in Spring MVC 3.
Is there an equivalent of [useDirectFieldAccess()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html#useDirectFieldAccess%28%29) method for annotated controllers?
I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [@InitBinder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html) annotation on a controller method, and then [initDirectFieldAccess](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#initDirectFieldAccess%28%29) on the recived WebDataBinder, documentation is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder).